# Is possible to change the price of an In App purchase after the Application is approved?

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

I have a very simple question:

Is it possible to change the price of an InApp product after the application is Approved?

It is a very simple/stupid question, but I need to make some decisions depending on InApp limits.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: hey did u changed the inapp purchase price tier after the app and inapp prdouct is approved?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, it is. You can change the price at any time in iTunes Connect.

Go to iTunes Connect -> *Manage Your Applications*

Select your application from the list.

To change application price click *Rights and Pricing* and you're there.

For In-App purchases prices you go to Manage *In-App purchases*, click on the
line of the InApp you're interested in and again you'te there.

Comment: Any official Apple reference Document on it?

Comment: @msmq: well that was 10 years ago so, knowing Apple, things have probably changed.

Comment: Price is still changeable. Thanks for the response

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is, but make sure you don't hard code the price.
Any label showing the price, pull the price from the products and localise the currency before adding to a label.
This way it'll always show the correct price in your app.

Comment: Have you done this?
how long it takes to have the new price in production?

Comment: I haven't done it on a released app, but tested an app during dev and it was instant.

Comment: On released application it also reflect instantly.