# Editable price in in-app purchase with iOS

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have an idea for an app but I want to know if it's possible to make the price of the in-app purchase elemet editable? Kind of donation where people can choose the amount they want to spend? I also want to know the limit(the maximum price) I can use for normal in-app purchase element.

Comment: i think you can change its price from iTunesConnect any time see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9915134/is-possible-to-change-the-price-of-an-in-app-purchase-after-the-application-is-a

Comment: The user can't edit the price; you would need to create a number of products at different prices and allow the user to choose which one they want to buy. The pricing levels are available in iTunesConnect and vary by region and from time to time